# When normal and poisson approximation is good/bad

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Normal approximation and poisson approximation is used to approximate binomial distribution.

when these approximation are good? when bad?

Comment: The normal approximation is good if the number of trials ($n$) is sufficiently large. The nearer the probability of success ($p$) is to $0.5$, the better the approximation is. A rough rule is : The approximation is good, if $np(1-p)>9$. The poisson-approximation is good if $n$ is large and $p$ is small

Answer (score 4):

The *Normal distribution* is *symmetric*. The binomial distribution is *symmetric* only when the *probability of success*, usually denoted by $p$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus if the departure of $p$ from $\frac{1}{2}$ is large, intuitively, it seems that it may not be good to use the *normal approximation*, which is the case if the *number of trials* $n$ is small. However, when $n$ is large, the *Normal approximation* stands solid by the very powerful *Central limit theorem*, which is basically the heart of *Large sample theory*.

On the other hand *Poisson approximation* is done by taking the parameter $\lambda$ to be equal to the product $n \times p$. It is good when $n$ is large, $p$ is small, but $n \times p$ is a finite quantity.Starting with the *probability mass function* of the *Binomial distribution*, taking the limits $n \to \infty$ and $p \to 0$, and putting $n \times p = \lambda$, one can get the *probability mass function* of the *Poisson distribution*. Obviously if these conditions (large $n$, small $p$ and finite $n \times p$) are violated, the *Poisson approximation* doesn't hold good.